# Hazelcast All or Nothing Eviction Policy

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Is there an eviction policy in Hazelcast allowing eviction of either an entire map or nothing at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get what you want using:

**eviction-percentage**: When max-size is reached, the specified percentage of the map is evicted. If 50 is set for example, 50% of the entries will be evicted.

Set your *max-size* to whatever value you want and then set your *eviction-percentage* to 100%. Then you will get all eviction at max size and nothing until then.